PXDBCalced property for use in PXRestrictor
I have the following PXDBCalced field added to CustomerExt:
    public abstract class isParent : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<isParent> { }

    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Is Parent")]
    [PXDBCalced(typeof(IIf<
    Exists<Select<BAccount,
           Where<BAccount.parentBAccountID, Equal<Customer.bAccountID>>>>,
    True, False>), typeof(bool))]
    public virtual bool? IsParent { get; set; }

Then using this in PXRestrictor in SOInvoiceExt graph extension:
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXRestrictor(
        typeof(Where<CustomerExt.isParent, Equal<False>>),
        "Account cannot be selected because it is a parent account.",
        typeof(Customer.acctCD))]
    protected void _(Events.CacheAttached<ARInvoice.customerID> e)
    {
    }

Which actually works and prevents selecting a parent customer on this type of document (need to add this to a handful of other graphs as well, some which bind to BAccountId and not Customer Id, but I digress)
Although this "works" it breaks customer maintenance (AR303000) with a stack overflow.  I assume there is a circular reference but not sure why it works in SOInvoiceEntry CustomerID and it also works in Customer GI if I add this field as a column in the grid results.
Any ideas how else I can implement this so as not to break AR303000?

Not sure why it happens. But as a workaround, you might try to code the same logic in the fieldupdated event of the customer.acctCD field?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can remove PXDBCalced attribute on CustomerMaint graph:
[PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXDBCalcedAttribute))]
protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<CustomerExt.isParent> e) {} 

